# using TFS for non-Microsoft Projects

Tags: php, tfs, tfvc

I work for a shop that has standardized on TFS.  We have one project that was  developed by a subcontractor in php.  You can't even load this thing in Visual Studio.

I managed to create a repo for the project, but I need to find out how to check the project in.  Is there some other app (like tortoiseSVN) that I can use to check stuff in and out without Visual Studio?  Or is there some way to get VS to load the project and check it in and out without creating a .sln, .csproj, or any other unwanted files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's totally possible to use Visual Studio to do this.

You can use the web interface to create a repo...

You can't edit the php in Visual Studio of course, but you can open the Source Control Explorer to check the project into the repo.

You need to remember to go in Visual Studio to check files out before you edit them, and then check them back in when you're done.

It's clunky, but not as clunky as buying a $200 per year setup we're only going to use a few days out of the year.  We're a Microsoft shop after all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using TFVC and not Git for version control.

If you don't have Visual Studio at all, you can install Team Explorer. If you already have Visual Studio installed, that's fine too.

The tool you're looking for is [`tf.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=vsts) -- it's the command line tool for interacting with TFVC.

You can also consider using a Git repo instead of TFVC for this -- although TFVC can be used for any type of source code, it has a reputation of being exclusively for Visual Studio-based projects. Git is likely to be more familiar to folks who have never worked with TFS or TFVC and have not spent much time using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), then install the TFS Integrartion plugin for it, then you can manage the php projects in PhpStorm same as manage projects in VS.

Just follow the steps mentioned in below screenshot to configure the PhpStorm:

More information you can refer to [Using TFS Integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-tfs-integration.html).

[image]

Comment: @Some_Yahoo Have you resolved the issue? any update?